# hybrid connection using azure hybrid cloud service

Tags: php, sql-server, azure, lan, hybrid

Installed with hybrid connection manager in my azure account. tried to connect local LAN server from azure web app.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/integration-hybrid-connection-create-manage/

Followed all steps above but no use. credentials of my local host are correct as i have connected SQL server from xampp PHP server.

All I want to know where might be the mistake.

Thanks,

Comment: VPN is what you referring?

Comment: Can the SSIS host machine/server see the SQL Server that you want to connect to?

Comment: Yes its showing all the machines/servers in the menu in connection manager